# Mongoose run instance method on exec

Tags: mongoose

I wish to populate the field 'details.location.displayAddress' using a bit of logic every time a document is requested. Is this possible? Want to avoid storing redundant data in my model.

In my Venue Controller I have 40+ different calls to this model. I would like to avoid manually calling the getShortName() on every single document returned. Is there a way to run this function automatically and define this logic in the model as opposed to the controller?

This is this model:

```
var VenueSchema = new Schema({

      name : {type : String, trim : true, lowercase : true, index: true, required: true}

    , details : {

        location : {
              unit : {type : String, trim : true, lowercase : true}
            , floor : {type : String, lowercase : true, trim : true}
            , streetNumber : {type : String, trim : true, lowercase : true}
            , streetName : {type : String, trim : true, lowercase : true, index: true}
            , suburb : {type : String, trim : true, lowercase : true}
            , city : {type : String, trim : true, lowercase : true}
            , postcode : {type : String, trim : true, lowercase : true, required: true}
            , state : {type : String, trim : true, lowercase : true, required: true}
            , country : {type : String, trim : true, lowercase : true}
            , displayAddress: POPULATE THIS FIELD ON EVERY QUERY
        }
    }
});

// Run this method everytime a document is requested and populate 'details.location.displayAddress'
VenueSchema.methods.getShortName = function() {
    pseudo code:
    this.details.location.displayAddress = this.name + this.location.unit + ' ' + this.details.location.floor ...etc
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you wanted here was a `.virtual()` method on the schema which will present the property in the document based on other properties of the document defined to return in the method:

```
VenueSchema.virtual('details.displayAddress').get(function() {
    return this.name + this.location.unit + ' ' + this.details.location.floor ...etc
});
```

It does not set "permantly" in the object but is accessible and available to serialize where required ( default ).

It's actually listed a bit further down [this page](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) after instance methods. Unlike "getters/setters" the data is not stored in the collection object.

Comment: Holy smokes! Exactly what I needed. Works like a charm. Thanks for your reply.